# Deadwood: a cheat, a broad tosser and a clip

Tags: dialogue, deadwood

I'm re-watching Deadwood, currently on Season 1 Episode 13, "Jewel's boot is made for walking". In this episode, Alma Garrett's father comes to town. While Alma, her father, Sophia and Seth Bullock are all sitting down to dinner in E.B. Farnum's hotel, E.B. is looking through a curtain and talking about the father. He says,

> the man's a cheat, a broad tosser, and a clip...

What does this sentence, these descriptions, signify that E.B. thinks of the father?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They all mean a con artist, an apt description of Alma's conniving, greedy father.

[Cheat](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cheat):

> One who cheats; a swindler.

[Broad-tosser](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=broad-tosser):

> The card dealer in the Three Card Monte con. [...] The con artist uses three cards, usually two black spot cards and a red Queen. [...] Monte hustlers usually work as a team, with a lookout and a third member who acts as a shill to win money and get the crowd involved in the betting.

[Clip artist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clip+artist):

> a swindler who fleeces the victim

Comment: Oh Walt. You may as well just say "Once again you see there is nothing you can possess which I cannot take away." Because like Belloq, you just took this answer from me... (Cries like someone afraid of snakes in a secret room below the desert full of snakes.)

Comment: Considering Belloq's fate, you should be happy. Sometimes it pays to [sit one out](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14508/is-amy-right-about-indiana-jones-being-irrelevant-to-the-outcome). ;)

Comment: And to think, I took 1st year Hovitos in high school... Chhh CCCHHHHKK!